Being a Torah-observant police officer in a secular country
I would like to know more about the ins and outs of being a police officer, as a frum Jew. What sort of issues come up?
Would be great to hear an account from someone who does this, such as a reference to a book they wrote, or even if a user here is one.
What are the halachic concerns and what does one have to think about in order to do their job properly without compromising halacha. E.g.

Yichud/negia, when handling suspects
Arresting fellow Jews
The attitude one should cultivate
Keeping one's temper in check
Applications of force

and much more..

As for police-activity on Shabbos, see here for instance.

https://hakirah.org/Vol24Friedman.pdf if you're seriously interested you can contact the author https://chaplainusa.org/rabbi-cary-friedman or check out his other books.
